# How to get the chosen file's extension from file dialog in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app. In my app I am using file dialog. But what my problem is, I want to retrieve the file extension of chosen file of file dialog.

This is the file dialog close call back of My Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                ivPreviewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I retrieve the file extension only?

### Update

This is the error in logcat. I declared your function in CommonHelper. The error line number of CommonHelper is the return line of your function.

```
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/73 }} to activity {com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion.CreateItemActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=25; index=-1
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=25; index=-1
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:579)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1438)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.model.CommonHelper.getExtensionFromUri(CommonHelper.java:126)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion.CreateItemActivity.onActivityResult(CreateItemActivity.java:288)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362) 
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141) 
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282) 
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
03-18 13:47:09.812 815-815/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

If your file have doted extension file, you could use this simple method:

```
public String getExtensionFromUri(Uri fileUri) {
    String filePath = fileUri.getPath();
    try {
        return filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    }catch(Exception e){
        return "no extension";
    }
}
```

Otherwise `MimeTypeMap` should help:

```
public String getMIMETypeFromUri(Uri fileUri) {
    try {
        ContentResolver cR = context.getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return  mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(fileUri));
    }catch(Exception e){
        return "no mime found";
    }
}
```

Here is how its looks like in your code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        Log.d(TAG,"Extension from selected file:" + getExtensionFromUri(filePath));   
        Log.d(TAG,"Extension from MIME:" + getMIMETypeFromUri(filePath));       
         try {
            //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
            ivPreviewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This is not working. Throwing error. I tried on this.

Comment: Please provide what error is throwing? I edited my answer.

Comment: Your selected image `//media/external/images/media/73` doesn't have  dot extension, so you are looking for **MIME**, as @CommonsWare said try `MimeTypeMap`

Comment: I edited my question and added `getMIMETypeFromUri` method

Comment: Did you have any issues with `getMIMETypeFromUri`. Please if you find our help valuable mark the question as solved ;)

Answer (score 2):

> In my app I am using file dialog

No, you appear to be using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or possibly `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Android does not have a "file dialog".

> I want to retrieve the file extension of chosen file of file dialog

There is no required file extension. It may not be a file.

This is not significantly different than how the Web works. This Web page is identified by this URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085617/how-to-get-the-chosen-files-extension-from-file-dialog-in-android
```

It is also identified by this URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/q/36085617/115145
```

Neither of those have a file extension, largely because there is no "file" for this Web page. It is generated from database entries and templates. Similarly, there is no "file" for content or documents.

The way you handle this in the Web, and in Android, is to use the MIME type. For a `Uri` (`data.getData()` in your example), you can use `ContentResovler` and `getType()` to determine the MIME type of the content represented by the `Uri`. This corresponds to the `Content-type` header of an HTTP response in Web development.

You are welcome to attempt to use `MimeTypeMap` to get a suggested file extension for the MIME type, though there may not be one. You are also welcome to [use `getLastPathSegment()` on the `Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getLastPathSegment%28%29), and see if there is a file extension on it, though there may not be one.

[This blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) covers more about how to consume content from a `Uri`.

Comment: How to get file extension using content resolver in my situation please ?